# Possible to make Hudson more resilient to minor networking hiccups?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

So, I have several jobs on Hudson that take 3-6 hours to run. The slave machines are a variety of different Windows operating systems running on VMs. Sometimes, there will be a minor hiccup that apparently will cause a socket that's been open for 6 hours to become closed. (which doesn't seem crazy even with perfect networking) And so, I end up with a stacktrace pointing to this:

```
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: socket closed
```

Is there any plugin or other way I could fix this extremely annoying problem? When you're 3 hours through a 4 hour build and it fails because of this, it's a bit infuriating.

Comment: The number of bug reports and mailing list postings I've seen with this exact issue is staggering, and not a single reply with a fix or even hint as to what the problem is. Just "me too".. I'm hoping stackoverflow can give me some kind of answer and serve as a reference to future googlers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe off topic, but have you considered an alternative CI server, like [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)? I've used it for 4 years on .NET projects and highly recommend them.

Comment: Primarily can't due to existing infrastructure. Probably 10 jenkins build slaves, about 40 separate builds relying extensively on some jenkins plugins. It'd just be too expensive to do.

Answer (score 0):

If build is running for 6 hours then it would fail if connection between Master-Slave breaks down.
So solution lies in creating a custom logic to connect to slave and Hudson provides an option for this. Check this link: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-WriteyourownscripttolaunchHudsonslaves

A custom script with retry logic should be the way out.